# VBA: Runtime 1004 -- Pasting to LastRow of another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to consolidate four separate tabs pulling only specific columns from each, that are in different locations on each source tab in order to build a pivottable/chart. This is for another user, so manual manipulation is not an option.

The first tab works appropriately because it's just a straight pull. Once I try to paste to the last row, things are weird. I've never had to do this task this way, so there might be some really fundamental concept I'm missing here causing the problem. I am using a method I found when doing my initial research on how to write the script.

Here's an example from the first tab that works:

```
'Copy and paste data from tab 1
Worksheets("redacteda").Range("H:H").Copy _
    Worksheets("Aggregate").Range("G:G")
```

Here's an example from the follow on tab that's resulting in the error:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Copy and Past data from tab 2
Worksheets("redactedb").Range("A:A").Copy _
    Worksheets("Aggregate").Range("A" & LastRow)
```

I tried Worksheets("Aggregate").Range("A & LastRow") as well, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You should add a sheet reference to LastRow. However, the main issue is that you are trying to copy a whole column to a range of a smaller size and you can't put a quart into a pint pot. I doubt you need to copy the whole column.

Comment: So I might need two LastRow variables then? One for the source sheet and one for the destination sheet, and add the sheet reference in front of the Cells( for each?

The columns are not defined in row count, so I could worksheets("redacted).range("A1":"A"&LastRow) to get the specific number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty much what you have suggested in your comment above. Of course this could still error if you are copying more cells than there are left on the destination sheet - so would need some error trapping for this probably unlikely event.

```
Sub x()

Dim LastRow1 As Long, LastRow2 As Long

With Worksheets("redactedb")
    LastRow1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow2 = Worksheets("Aggregate").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range("A1", .Range("A" & LastRow1)).Copy Worksheets("Aggregate").Range("A" & LastRow2)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Solution Verified. This is the option I went with, worked like a charm and I learned some stuff along the way. Thanks SJR.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be adaptable for you...

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, i As Long, CopyRange As Range, LastRow As Long

    ' Initialize array with sheet names to combine
    Dim SrcArr() As String: SrcArr = Split("Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3,Sheet4", ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(SrcArr)
        On Error Resume Next
            LastRow = wsDest.Range("A:A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SrcArr(i))
        With wsSrc
            Set CopyRange = Application.Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("A:A"))
            CopyRange.Copy wsDest.Range("A" & LastRow + 1)
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```